# Promise created in handler but not returned

Tags: node.js, controller, sails.js

This warning has come up since I updated sails.js to version 0.12.0:

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
at Deferred.toPromise (K/trunk/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:494:61)
at Deferred.then (K/trunk/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:505:15)
```

It happens in a controller which gets info from a model, then needs to update a entry in the model.

```
ExampleModel.findOne()
..
.then(function (){
   ExampleModel.update({id:nid},{amount:newamount})
   .then(function (updates){
      return.json(updates);
   }
```

Im not sure how to fix this issue? It is just a warning but would like to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ExampleModel.findOne()
  .then(function (){
     return ExampleModel.update({id:nid},{amount:newamount})
       .then(function (updates){
          return.json(updates);
       }
```